Where is the Anisotropy BSDF in Blender 4.1?
I can't find the Anisotropy BSDF. Where can I find it in Blender 4.1?

@RobinBetts ok sure. I find it weird though because they claim that Anisotropic BSDF exists in Blender 3.6.0 https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/3.6/render/shader_nodes/shader/anisotropic.html but I can't find it there when I checked.

@HarryMcKenzie Nor me, in 3.6.4 .. strange.. only accessible through Principled, and the Tangent input miles away like an afterthought

The Glossy and Anisotropic BSDF shaders have been combined into a single Glossy BSDF shader with an Anisotropy attribute.

